# How to add date older than 3 years in current date column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
code    fat_version bat_version  from_date   to_date
102     1.7         2.5          2019-01-02  2019-04-16
102     3.5         7.1.5        2019-04-16  2020-04-16
347     6.55        6.55         2019-06-04  2020-04-16
107     6.55        6.55         2019-01-18  2019-04-05
107     6.55        6.55         2019-04-05  2020-04-16
```

What I want to do is to add date older than 3 years to least from_date and make corresponding `fat_varsion` and `bat_version` as `nan` grouping by code level. My desired dataframe would be as follows

```
code    fat_version bat_version  from_date   to_date
102     nan         nan          2016-01-02  2019-01-01 
102     1.7         2.5          2019-01-02  2019-04-16
102     3.5         7.1.5        2019-04-16  2020-04-16
347     nan         nan          2016-06-04  2019-06-03
347     6.55        6.55         2019-06-04  2020-04-16
107     nan         nan          2016-01-18  2019-01-17 
107     6.55        6.55         2019-01-18  2019-04-05
107     6.55        6.55         2019-04-05  2020-04-16
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Comment: What is the problem? The dates older than three years (i.e. you do not have a problem with younger years)? Or the nan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get first rows per groups by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), change values in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with add 3 years by [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html), then join to original and sorting:

```
df['from_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from_date'])
df['to_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['to_date'])

df1 = (df.drop_duplicates('code')
        .assign(to_date = lambda x: x['from_date'],
                from_date = lambda x: x['from_date'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=3),
                fat_version = np.nan, 
                bat_version = np.nan))
print (df1)
   code  fat_version  bat_version  from_date    to_date
0   102          NaN          NaN 2016-01-02 2019-01-02
2   347          NaN          NaN 2016-06-04 2019-06-04
3   107          NaN          NaN 2016-01-18 2019-01-18

df = pd.concat([df1, df], ignore_index=True).sort_values('code')
print (df)
   code  fat_version bat_version  from_date    to_date
0   102          NaN         NaN 2016-01-02 2019-01-02
3   102         1.70         2.5 2019-01-02 2019-04-16
4   102         3.50       7.1.5 2019-04-16 2020-04-16
2   107          NaN         NaN 2016-01-18 2019-01-18
6   107         6.55        6.55 2019-01-18 2019-04-05
7   107         6.55        6.55 2019-04-05 2020-04-16
1   347          NaN         NaN 2016-06-04 2019-06-04
5   347         6.55        6.55 2019-06-04 2020-04-16
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as always. from_date should be older than 3 years that is being correctly mapped, but in to_date it should be same as next `from_date`. Please check my desired dataframe.

Comment: @Neil - I change order in `assign`, now it should be correct.

Comment: can we do one more change while mapping the date older than 3 years. So instead of same date we can do t - 1 date. I am updating my desired dataframe

Comment: @Neil - Can you test changed `assign` like `.assign(to_date = lambda x: x['from_date'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1),
                from_date = lambda x: x['from_date'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=3) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=1),
                fat_version = np.nan, 
                bat_version = np.nan))` ?